# Passing value from previous page to django view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a job site where a user enters a zip code into a form and a list of jobs matching that zip code is displayed 
search.html :

```
<h6>Results: {{ number_of_results }}</h6>

            {% for job in jobs_matching_query %}

                    <h2><a class="job_link" href="#">{{ job.job_title}}</a></h2>
                    <p class="job_address lead">{{ job.establishment_name }} - {{ job.address }}</p>

            {% endfor %}

        <form action = "{% url 'email_subscription' %}">
            <p>Subscribe to recieve job alerts near {{ query }}:</p> <!-- query stores zip code-->
            <input type="text" name= "email" placeholder="Email">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
        </form>
```

The search form is handled by the following view (not sure if I need to include this or not):

```
def job_query(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        query = request.GET.get('query')
        jobs_matching_query = Job.objects.filter(zip_code__iexact = query) | Job.objects.filter(city__iexact=query) | Job.objects.filter(state__iexact=query)
        number_of_results = 0
        for job in jobs_matching_query:
            number_of_results = number_of_results + 1
        return render(request, 'core/search.html', {'query': query ,'jobs_matching_query': jobs_matching_query, 'number_of_results': number_of_results})
```

On that search.html I have an email subscription box (subscribe to recieve alerts for that particular zip code), is there a way to pass the value of `query` from that page to an `email_subscription` view? I believe I've seen this done in the url so here is the url for said view

```
url(r'^email_subscription$', views.email_subscription, name="email_subscription"),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use django sesions for that you can save the query in django session

```
#put it somewhere 
request.session['query'] = my_query 
#then you can access it from the other view in views.email_subscription
```

it is going to work but im not sure if this is a practitacal one